# Test and production situated on the same LAN

Tags: local-area-network

The organisation who are responsible for our Data Centre have just advised me that the Testing and production environments are running off the same LAN.  To me this sounds like bad practice what - couldn't testing cause a potential performance issue on the LAN which knocks onto the performance of the production app.
Am I missing something here and worrying about nothing?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to tell.  What do you and they mean by environment?  I've often heard the whole stack of a web application referred to as an environment - but it wouldn't necessarily be critical to have test and production on different LANs.  I've seen it done on the same machine!

Comment: It depends on the type of testing, if it is network load testing then I might be concerned....however if whatever is running is just an application then I would probably be less worried.

Comment: It also depends on what they are testing. If the testing is just localized, then who cares. . .

Comment: The real problem here is with well meaning people making blanket statements like "Your test and production environments are on the same LAN and that's bad" without having any knowledge of the systems involved. For now, let's ignore what the datacenter Ops people told you and focus on determining what might be "bad" about it. How about if you give us more details from which we can formulate relatively informed answers.

Answer (score 3):

I'd agree it's bad practice, for exactly the reason you state.

Of course the severity of the worry depends to some extent on how busy those networks are, whether they're VLAN'ed in any way, if there are per-VLAN quotas/limits etc. i.e. you *could* build a very safe scenario such as this but that's far from the default, so you have justification to worry yes.

Comment: I would suggest until we know what 'the same LAN' means, we can't be sure.  It could be a huge enterprise network covering several acres of site, or a single switch in a small office.